# Websphere class loading profile restart verus application restart

Tags: java, websphere

Can anyone tell me if Websphere does anything differently in terms of class loading when a profile is restarted as opposed to then an application within that profile is restarted?

I'm dealing with a large scale enterprise application compiled against Java 8 that has 250+ third party JAR files in its \WEB-INF\lib folder and am experiencing different behaviour on Websphere 9.0.0.2 (Build Number: cf021645.01 Build Date: 11/8/16) in that everything works fine with the application when I restart the profile but it breaks with what appear to be class loading related errors deep down in third party JAR code whenever the application itself is subsequently restarted.

I have looked at the class loader viewer, turned on verbose class loading and configured a diagnostic trace and everything appears to me to be being loaded correctly.  I have two instances of the same application deployed in different profiles using the same version of Websphere and the behaviour is consistent between both, restart the profile and the application is all good but then restart the application and things go bad.

We have only recently started to deploy our application on WebSphere 9, prior to that we were deploying a version of it that was compiled against Java 6 to Websphere 7 without any issues.  Some of the third party JARs being used are quite old as our dependency management (or lack thereof) is in need of some work but at this stage I am reluctant to commence what could turn out to be a significant task of updating libraries when the application works fine in one case but not another.

More info added:

Below is an example of the type of error I get following an application restart.  In this particular instance I'm running some of our application code that reads a Word document from the file system and passes it to a third party PDF generation library so the execution goes from our local code into the PDF generation library then into the imageio.  I don't always get the same error, it sometimes fails at a different point following another application restart (making it further down into the imageio code) but imageio always seems to lead to the problem.

Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: it/geosolutions/imageio/plugins/arcgrid/raster/AsciiGridRaster$AsciiGridRasterType
    at it.geosolutions.imageio.plugins.arcgrid.spi.AsciiGridsImageReaderSpi.canDecodeInput(AsciiGridsImageReaderSpi.java:216)
    at javax.imageio.ImageIO$CanDecodeInputFilter.filter(ImageIO.java:578)
    at javax.imageio.spi.FilterIterator.advance(ServiceRegistry.java:832)
    at javax.imageio.spi.FilterIterator.(ServiceRegistry.java:826)
    at javax.imageio.spi.ServiceRegistry.getServiceProviders(ServiceRegistry.java:527)
    at javax.imageio.ImageIO.getImageReaders(ImageIO.java:657)
    at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(ImageIO.java:1449)
    at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(ImageIO.java:1363)

From what I can see we don't appear to be using any shared libraries at all.

I did stumble upon this question on here during earlier investigations into my issue [Not able to load javax.imageio.ImageIO class in WAS 8.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42840693/not-able-to-load-javax-imageio-imageio-class-in-was-8-5/42866011#42866011) and I can confirm we are already doing point 1 (explicitly calling ImageIO.scanForPlugins(), we do it as part of a servlet that executes on our application start up) and I have also configured point 2 (disable the class loader leak prevention in the server with a system property com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.disableMemoryLeakService=true) in attempts to diagnose my problem.  I haven't tried point 3 though as it seemed to me to be a bit of a last resort.

With regard to imageio we have the following JARs being deployed as part of the 250+ within our application:

jai_codec
jai_imageio
jai_core
imageio-ext-arcgrid-1.1.10
imageio-ext-streams-1.1.10
imageio-ext-utilities-1.1.10

I'm unsure of the exact versions of the jai JARs but will endeavour to find out.

We also deploy a whole bunch of geotools JARs as well and sometimes it fails down in those following execution through imageio.  All of these geotools JARs are version 2.4.0 which I know is quite old and I'm not sure how backward compatible they are running on Java 8 now.  They worked fine for us on Websphere 7 Java 6 even though I think geotools 2.4.0 was aligned with Java 1.4.  Again I'm reluctant to start updating libraries when the application works fine in one case but not another.

Comment: Can you provide more details?  What is the error message?  And can you post the stack trace?  From your description, it sounds like something is hanging around / leaking.  Are you using any isolated shared libraries, or server shared libraries?  Restarting just the app will create new classloaders for the newly-restarted app, but other classloaders will remain - and it is possible that a class loaded in one of those other classloaders are holding a reference to something loaded from the app - leaking the loader, but possibly causing other problems too. HTH, Andy

Comment: Thanks for the response @AndyMcCright, as a dev with a very limited knowledge of Websphere your help is much appreciated.  I've added some more info, hope it gives you a bit more to go on.